# agm-marker onMouseOver open agm-info-window

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3

I using [Angular Google Maps(AGM)](https://angular-maps.com/) componet.
I need to open info window on marker mouse hover.
How can I retreive the `infowindow` instance in my function `onMouseOver` to open it?

```
<agm-map [fitBounds]="latlngBounds" [zoom]="15">
    <agm-marker *ngFor="let m of markers; let i = index"
                [latitude]="m.geoCode.latitude"
                [longitude]="m.geoCode.longitude"
                (mouseOver)="onMouseOver(m)"
                >

        <agm-info-window [disableAutoPan]="false">

            <div>
                <a (click)="onClickInfoView({id:m.id})" class="btn btn-attention pull-right">test<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
            </div>

        </agm-info-window>


    </agm-marker>

</agm-map>



onMouseOver(data) {
        ???? /* how to open here the info window?
    }
```

Answer (score 19):

At the end I found a solution:

```
<agm-map #gm [fitBounds]="latlngBounds" [zoom]="15">
    <agm-marker *ngFor="let m of markers; let i = index"
                [latitude]="m.geoCode.latitude"
                [longitude]="m.geoCode.longitude"
                (mouseOver)="onMouseOver(infoWindow,gm)"
                >

        <agm-info-window [disableAutoPan]="false" #infoWindow>

            <div>
                {{m.name}}
                {{m.rating}}
            </div>
            <div>
                <a (click)="onClickInfoView({id:m.id})" class="btn btn-attention pull-right">Daje <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
            </div>

        </agm-info-window>


    </agm-marker>

</agm-map>


onMouseOver(infoWindow, gm) {

        if (gm.lastOpen != null) {
            gm.lastOpen.close();
        }

        gm.lastOpen = infoWindow;

        infoWindow.open();
    }
```

Comment: Hi Pizzoni. I want to open the agm-snazzy-info-window on MapLoad at a particular location. ( without a MapCLick) I am using Angular 4. Can you please help.

Comment: @Pizzoni Alessio I get the error that infoWindow doesn't have .open() function

Comment: @John In markup you have passing infowindows? (mouseOver)="onMouseOver(infoWindow,gm)"

Answer (score 16):

You can add a mouseOut event and create a function to close the InfoWindow onMouseOut

```
    <agm-map #gm [fitBounds]="latlngBounds" [zoom]="15">
    <agm-marker *ngFor="let m of markers; let i = index"
                [latitude]="m.geoCode.latitude"
                [longitude]="m.geoCode.longitude"
                (mouseOver)="onMouseOver(infoWindow, $event)" 
                (mouseOut)="onMouseOut(infoWindow, $event)"
                >

        <agm-info-window [disableAutoPan]="false" #infoWindow>

            <div>
                {{m.name}}
                {{m.rating}}
            </div>
            <div>
                <a (click)="onClickInfoView({id:m.id})" class="btn btn-attention pull-right">Daje <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
            </div>

        </agm-info-window>


    </agm-marker>

</agm-map>


onMouseOver(infoWindow, $event: MouseEvent) {
        infoWindow.open();
    }

onMouseOut(infoWindow, $event: MouseEvent) {
        infoWindow.close();
    }
```

Comment: infoWindow.lastOpen.close();

Answer (score 2):

In my case, onMouseover() only worked if I set it to

```
onMouseOver(infoWindow, gm) {

  if (gm.lastOpen && gm.lastOpen.isOpen) {
    gm.lastOpen.close();
  }

  gm.lastOpen = infoWindow;

  infoWindow.open();
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error with the solution above whenever the infoPane closed for another reason (user clicked off) so I tried this.. but this doesn't work because gm.lastOpen.isOpen is always false, so now none of the infoPanes close